# How to substitute by NDSolve solution to plot a new function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex

Assume I got some function by `NDSolve` , like `y(t)`

`ysol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}]`

How can I plot another new function defined by

`ycomp = ysol + I ysol` ?

where `t` is time. So I think the problem is that, the true independent parameter is `t` and it's real, but when I plot `ycomp` versus `ysol` in the complex plane , `ysol` will be the independent parameter .

For example, if `ComplexPlot3D` is used, it's simple in forward solutions , like:

`ComplexPlot3D[y, {y, 0 + 0 I, 1 + I}]`

But in my case , how to embed `NDSolve` solution in the plot of 
a new function ?

Hope my argument is clear enough. 
And any help to do that is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ysol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[t] /. ysol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

`y[t]` is only defined for a real arguments.

```
ycompAbs[t_] = y[Abs[t]] + I y[Abs[t]] /. ysol;

ycompRe[t_] = y[Re[t]] + I y[Re[t]] /. ysol;

ycompIm[t_] = y[Im[t]] + I y[Im[t]] /. ysol;

Column[ComplexPlot3D[#, {t, 0 + 0 I, 1 + I},
    ImageSize -> 360] & /@ {ycompAbs[t], ycompRe[t], ycompIm[t]}]
```

[image]